# Acer Aspire One 751h multimedia support

Tags: sound, kernel, acer, realtek, gma500

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my Acer Aspire One 751h netbook. Recently I updated my Linux kernel to 3.11.08-18. Thankfully my video works awesome, but there is no sound.

I have Realtek Audio hardware and Dolby speakers. Earlier in Kubuntu 12.10 with kernel 3.5 series it worked out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo depmod -a` command, sometimes it helps after updating kernel in ubuntu.

Comment: FATAL: Could not open /lib/modules/3.11.0-18-generic/modules.dep.temp for writing: Permission denied

Comment: This is the error am facing...

Comment: Sorry, `sudo depmod -a`, I'll update my answer.